# Migrating SDL_PeepEvents From SDL 1.2.14 to SDL 1.3

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, ios, sdl

I'm porting an OS X application written in C++ with the SDL 1.2 framework to iOS using the SDL 1.3 framework.  There have been some changes to the methods, and I am having trouble rewriting a couple of pieces of code. Here are the comments and declarations for the SDL_PeepEvents method from 1.2.14:

```
/**
 *  Checks the event queue for messages and optionally returns them.
 *
 *  If 'action' is SDL_ADDEVENT, up to 'numevents' events will be added to
 *  the back of the event queue.
 *  If 'action' is SDL_PEEKEVENT, up to 'numevents' events at the front
 *  of the event queue, matching 'mask', will be returned and will not
 *  be removed from the queue.
 *  If 'action' is SDL_GETEVENT, up to 'numevents' events at the front 
 *  of the event queue, matching 'mask', will be returned and will be
 *  removed from the queue.
 *
 *  @return
 *  This function returns the number of events actually stored, or -1
 *  if there was an error.
 *
 *  This function is thread-safe.
 */
extern DECLSPEC int SDLCALL SDL_PeepEvents(SDL_Event *events, int numevents,
                SDL_eventaction action, Uint32 mask);
```

Here is the declaration for the same method in 1.3:

```
/**
 *  Checks the event queue for messages and optionally returns them.
 *  
 *  If \c action is ::SDL_ADDEVENT, up to \c numevents events will be added to
 *  the back of the event queue.
 *  
 *  If \c action is ::SDL_PEEKEVENT, up to \c numevents events at the front
 *  of the event queue, within the specified minimum and maximum type,
 *  will be returned and will not be removed from the queue.
 *  
 *  If \c action is ::SDL_GETEVENT, up to \c numevents events at the front 
 *  of the event queue, within the specified minimum and maximum type,
 *  will be returned and will be removed from the queue.
 *  
 *  \return The number of events actually stored, or -1 if there was an error.
 *  
 *  This function is thread-safe.
 */
extern DECLSPEC int SDLCALL SDL_PeepEvents(SDL_Event * events, int numevents,
                                           SDL_eventaction action,
                                           Uint32 minType, Uint32 maxType);
```

Finally, here is the method I am trying to rewrite:

```
/**
 * Returns true if the queue is empty of events that match 'mask'. 
 */
 bool EventHandler::timerQueueEmpty() {
    SDL_Event event;

    if (SDL_PeepEvents(&event, 1, SDL_PEEKEVENT, SDL_EVENTMASK(SDL_USEREVENT)))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

It currently throws the following error when compiling - 'SDL_EVENTMASK' was not declared in this scope.  I fully understand that the error is occurring because SDL_EVENTMASK is no longer a parameter of the SDL_PeepEvents function.  I also understand that Uint32Mask has been replaced by Uint32 minType, Uint32 maxType.  I just having a hard time understanding how to rewrite the code with these new parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDL 1.3, as you have stated uses event range instead of event mask. This code should work with SDL 1.3:

```
SDL_PeepEvents(&event, 1, SDL_PEEKEVENT, SDL_USEREVENT, SDL_NUMEVENTS - 1);  // Peek events in the user range
```

Another cosmetic thing - you do not have to check with an if for boolean variables and then return true/false:

```
/**
 * Returns true if the queue is empty of events that match 'mask'. 
 */
 bool EventHandler::timerQueueEmpty() {
    SDL_Event event;

    return SDL_PeepEvents(&event, 1, SDL_PEEKEVENT, SDL_USEREVENT, SDL_NUMEVENTS - 1) != 0;
}
```